# Merge Dataframe with conditional statements in R

Tags: r, merge, conditional-statements

I would like to merge two dataframes based on two conditions, one of which examines the percent match across two rows. In the following example, I would like to force a perfect match across the variable x and a match across y based on if there is any unique letter match:

```
f1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c("aa", "ff", "cd"), z = c(4,5,6))
f2 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c("aa", "bb", "cc"), z = c(7,9,10))
```

To produce:

```
1 1  aa   4  aa   7
3 3  cd   6  cc  10
```

Ultimately, I would like to figure out how to include a function in the merge that looks through conditions. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if `f2 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3, 4), y = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"), z = c(7,9,10, 11))`? Are these 1:many matches?

Comment: In this case, the match would not go to the fourth row since they don't match on x.

Comment: But the "cd" value in `f1` would match to both row 3 and 4 in `f2`.

Comment: Indeed, but the variable "x" would not match on those (it is 3 in f1 and 4 in f2).

Comment: Ok, fine, what about `f2 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,3), y = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"), z = c(7,9,10, 11))` The point is, what if there is a partial match to more than one element on the second column.

Comment: Ahh, I see (sorry about). For a partial match to more than one element, it would be great to generate two matches (i.e. one for row 4 and one for row 4).