# How to merge two dataframes with conditional statements

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, conditional-statements

I have two `df` I want to `merge`.

`df1` looks like this:

```
CODE    TAX   PRICE   TOTAL
4577    0.9   99.1    100
8965    NA    25      25
7788    1.5   13.5    15
4021    NA    20      20
6987    0.00  40      40
```

`df1` is a `dataframe` containing codes, tax cost depending on prices and the total (sum) of taxes + prices.

`df2` looks like this:

```
CODE    TAX.CLASS   MEANING
4577     CLASS1     Car
4577     CLASS2     Car
8965     CLASS1     Internet
2635     CLASS1     Computer
7788     CLASS1     Phone
7788     CLASS2     Phone
1258     CLASS1     Water
4021     CLASS1     Food
6987     CLASS1     Gasoline
6987     CLASS2     Gasoline
```

where each `code` displays a `tax.class` and `meaning`.
I would like to get an output like this:

```
CODE    MEANING   TAX.CLASS   TAX   PRICE   TOTAL
4577    Car        CLASS2     0.9   99.1    100
8965    Internet   CLASS1     NA    25      25
7788    Phone      CLASS2     1.5   13.5    15
4021    Food       CLASS1     NA    20      20
6987    Gasoline   CLASS1     0.00  40      40
```

So far I have tried with the answers of these questions:

- [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)
- [How to merge two dataframes in R conditionally (common column, condition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618808/how-to-merge-two-dataframes-in-r-conditionally-common-column-condition)
- [Merge 2 dataframes based on condition in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287995/merge-2-dataframes-based-on-condition-in-r)
- [Merge Dataframe with conditional statements in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702633/merge-dataframe-with-conditional-statements-in-r)

but it has not worked as I want. The issue basically is to `match` every `code` in `df1` with the `code` in `df2` but retrieving `CLASS1` if there is `NA` or a `TAX` value in `df1 <= 0.00`, on the other hand, retrieve `CLASS2` if there is a `TAX` value in `df1 > 0.00` on `codes` repeated twice.

Any suggestions?

Preferably `BaseR`.

Comment: There's no column called "value". What are you referring to?

Comment: I meant, `TAX` value in `df1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
df1$TAX.CLASS<- ifelse(is.na(df1$TAX) | df1$TAX <= 0.00, "CLASS1", "CLASS2")

df_final <- merge(df1, df2, by = c("CODE", "TAX.CLASS"), all.x = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
   CODE TAX.CLASS TAX PRICE TOTAL  MEANING
1: 4021    CLASS1  NA  20.0    20     Food
2: 4577    CLASS2 0.9  99.1   100      Car
3: 6987    CLASS1 0.0  40.0    40 Gasoline
4: 7788    CLASS2 1.5  13.5    15    Phone
5: 8965    CLASS1  NA  25.0    25 Internet
```

This is a solution in `base`, but the same logic can be applied in any package.

Note that you could also use `with` in the first statement to avoid referencing the data frame:

```
df1$TAX.CLASS<- with(df1, ifelse(is.na(TAX) | TAX <= 0.00, "CLASS1", "CLASS2"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, we can create a TAX.CLASS in `df1`, and then `left_join`.

```
df1 %>% dplyr::mutate(TAX.CLASS=ifelse(TAX<=0 | is.na(TAX),"CLASS1","CLASS2")) %>%
  dplyr::left_join(df2, by=c("CODE","TAX.CLASS"))

  CODE TAX PRICE TOTAL TAX.CLASS  MEANING
1 4577 0.9  99.1   100    CLASS2      Car
2 8965  NA  25.0    25    CLASS1 Internet
3 7788 1.5  13.5    15    CLASS2    Phone
4 4021  NA  20.0    20    CLASS1     Food
5 6987 0.0  40.0    40    CLASS1 Gasoline
```